# System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task): HRESULT: 0x80640012

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, wifi-direct

```
    private static async void OnConnectionRequestedAsync(WiFiDirectConnectionListener sender, WiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        WiFiDirectConnectionRequest connectionRequest = eventArgs.GetConnectionRequest();
        string deviceName = connectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Name;
        string deviceID = connectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Id;

        DeviceInformation devinfo = connectionRequest.DeviceInformation;
        bool isPaired = (devinfo.Pairing?.IsPaired == true) ||
                        (await IsAepPairedAsync(deviceID));
        try
        {
            // IMPORTANT: FromIdAsync needs to be called from the UI thread
            if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                _wfdDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceID);
            }
            else
            {
                await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(async () =>
                {
                    _wfdDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceID); // Exception Line
                }));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Data($"Exception in FromIdAsync: {ex.Message}, StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}\n\r");
        }
    }
```

Still getting below error:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80640012
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x80640012
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TestApp.WifiDirectPublisher.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<OnConnectionRequestedAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\git\TestApp\WifiDirectPublisher.cs:line 75
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are you developing a WPF project?

Comment: Yes @RoyLi-MSFT, I switch back from UWP to WPF to avoid consent popup.

Comment: btw, I am trying to connect from Android device to Windows.

Comment: I checked the error code, the description is **The client cannot acquire a context for the AEP because another client already has**. Is the device being connected to other apps before you are trying to connect to it?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT no, this is the only app that trying to connect. No other WD connection is there. How can I check the status programmatically before the request?

Answer (score -1):

add the code below:

```cs
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2000);
```

Comment: can you be more specific about where in the code?